# Build input file cannot be found - whole folder?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Hi guys,

I am a little bit desperate now. I reinstalled Xcode and want to compile my app (built via react native) now. I never had an issue with that before.

But now I am receiving the following issue, when trying to compile it.

```
CopySwiftLibs /Users/meX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/helloDay-hgejsbaehecevlcymblniafdiwuf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/helloDay.app (in target 'helloDay' from project 'helloDay')
    cd /Users/meX/Desktop/appdev/helloday/ios
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export DEVELOPER_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export SDKROOT\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.1.sdk
    builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose --sign EFF36FE468485687AFFCFCC98FDEC1B855FFF75C --scan-executable /Users/meX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/helloDay-hgejsbaehecevlcymblniafdiwuf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/helloDay.app/helloDay --scan-folder /Users/meX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/helloDay-hgejsbaehecevlcymblniafdiwuf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/helloDay.app/Frameworks --scan-folder /Users/meX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/helloDay-hgejsbaehecevlcymblniafdiwuf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/helloDay.app/PlugIns --platform iphoneos --toolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain --destination /Users/meX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/helloDay-hgejsbaehecevlcymblniafdiwuf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/helloDay.app/Frameworks --strip-bitcode --strip-bitcode-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip --emit-dependency-info /Users/meX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/helloDay-hgejsbaehecevlcymblniafdiwuf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/helloDay.build/Release-iphoneos/helloDay.build/SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep

error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/meX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/helloDay-hgejsbaehecevlcymblniafdiwuf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/helloDay.app/helloDay' (in target 'helloDay' from project 'helloDay')
```

As you can see, it is a little bit weird, since it is not referring to one file, but to a whole folder? Or am I blind here?

Just running the app in debug is working without any issue.

Thanks a lot,

Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not delete this, but I was able to solve this issue. I have no idea, what was going on here. But I solved it like that:

I just created a whole new project and copied over the .xcodeproj file. After configuring everything I tried to build the app and everything worked.

Maybe it will help someone as well. Good luck!